# Running an Oracle SQL update script daily

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I was wondering what the quickest, easiest and most efficient way of running some SQL code daily is? We have a number of update scripts that we'd like to run, with no easy way of doing so right now. I cannot seem to find any option in Oracle SQL Developer for this.

(I guess one way could be to run a PHP file every night, although from experience it has serious permission issues, and also opens an instance of IE every night with no way of closing it afterwards)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Oracle database has many options for running scheduled jobs, which means you do not have to rely on the operating system (like cron in Linux/Unix).

You can use the older [DBMS_JOB](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_job.html) package or the newer and more sophisticated [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Scheduler10g.php) is also available in 10g.

example:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'gather_stats_for_scott', -- this name is arbitrary 
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', --see possible job types here http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1000363
    job_action      => 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(''SCOTT''); END;',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP, --start now
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily',
    end_date        => NULL,
    enabled         => TRUE,
    comments        => 'This job does this and that' --arbitrary comment
  );
END
```

Comment: this could be fantastic, thank you! looking into implementing it now :)

Answer (score 3):

There a numerous options the two simplest that spring to mind are platform dependant:

### Windows

Set up a Windows Scheduled task which will run @ defined periods by you. You can use this to call either SQLPLUS directly and run your script, or if you want to handle the output you could wrap this is in a batch file?

### Unix / Linux / Mac

The Unixy equivilant to scheduled tasks is CRON jobs, they work in a similar way, and again you could call SQLPLUS directly, or you can call a shell script to handle output / errors etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I like the idea of running it through SQPLUS, but having not heard of this I will look into it now, and also have to speak with IT to see if it's possible to get it installed on the server. Also, we already have batch files that will run procedures, but they are a bit of a faff I find, and won't run simple/basic SQL. Not a fan of the cursors.

Comment: Batch files should be fine - you can make a call to SQLPLUS with a connection and pass it a reference to a SQL script file...

Answer (score 1):

A cron job on linux/unix like systems or a scheduled task on windows